# How to Switch MapType of MKMapView without a jerk in the mapView

Tags: ios, mapkit, apple-maps

If I am switching MapType on press of UIButton, then the entire map blacks out and loads from the beginning. Just as in Apple Maps App, when the MapType is changed I would like to have my Map reload instantaneously with Labels and the Vice Versa!.

How to solve this Glitch?

Comment: Well I don't see any unusual glitch, its just that it takes time to load and it depends on your internet speed.

Comment: Changing the value in MapType property may cause the receiver to begin loading new map content which is quite obvious. As @Puneet mentioned, it would be your data connection which is taking longer to render the MKMapView. The glitch you mentioned cannot be solved programmatically.

Comment: In the Apple Maps App, labels get overlayed without the map getting reloaded.However when I do the same thing programatically,the entire map reloads. I am looking for a way to avoid this and make my map work like apple Maps App!